# Can "interesting" be used to show doubt when replying?

Tags: word-usage

Here is an example (Comment to answer to *[Replacing a 32-bit loop count variable with 64-bit introduces crazy performance deviations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078285/replacing-a-32-bit-loop-count-variable-with-64-bit-introduces-crazy-performance?rq=1#comment39018334_25078871)*):

> Interesting, can you add compiler version and compiler flags? *The best thing is that on your machine, the results are turned around, i.e., using u64 is faster.* Until now, I have never thought about which type my loop variable has, but it seems I have to think twice next time :).

I also have seen many times that people use "interesting" and **guess** they want to show that they doubt about or don't agree on another one's answer, just like the example above.

But, I am not sure my guess. So, can "interesting" be used to show doubt when replying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Any* words can be used in a variety of ways depending on context and intonation.  I think in this English is no different from any other language.

In your example, the comment starts with "interesting" to indicate the person's interest in the proposed solution.  There is no *doubt* that the solution is correct, but the comment does ask for some enhancement.

In a different context, "interesting" might indicate something else is "of interest" -- such as what the heck the person might have been thinking, which does express a kind of doubt.

> A: You ate orange with chocolate?  That's an ... **interesting** combination.
>   B: No, it was surprisingly good! You should try it.